# Swagger fails to fetch when I select changed uploaded file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I have a controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UploadFileController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFiles(
        IFormFile file)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I open Swagger UI and upload file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCMO1.png)
I receive 200 - it is OK.

But when I change this file in text editor and select it again - it fails.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0mX9.png)
Only after reloading all page it will work fine. But it is not comfortable.

What should I do to fix this?
I use .net core 7

I expect that it will be 200 again.
I tried to find answers in the same topics here, but there is no helpful information.

Comment: If I select a file in swagger but edit it in my pc then send request also show this error, I search a lot but I don't find related docs about it, Now the only solution is after you edit this file, you need to select it again.